# What is this error which I get when storing data from form to database table on localhost

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

Guys I was trying to store data from my signup form to database `'abc'` inside `'user'` table but I get below error :-

> Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found:
>   1146 Table 'labun.reg_users' doesn't exist

I used localhost and I have to run my localhost as localhost:8080

Comment: `'abc' inside 'user' table` and `Table 'labun.reg_users'` So what it the table name - USER or USERS? What is databese name - abc or labun?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Table 'labun.reg_users' doesn't exist

The error is self explanatory and it clearly says that there is no table named `reg_users` under database `labun`. Considering `labun` is your database name and you are using default `dbo` schema.

Check whether you really have a table with that name. You can connect to your `MySQL` server and use below commands

```
use labun; //use the database in question
show tables; //list out all the tables in that DB
```

Comment: Use the correct table name saying `labun.users_temp_dbase`

Comment: how can i fix that bro?I mean i have made users_temp_dbase table on my database and I have used that same table name on my php file also but i don't know from where that unknown reg_users table come.

Comment: Can you say bro what might be the main reason of such problem?I mean how it occurs?

Comment: bro I was using reg_users table to check email already exist which wasn't yet created haha..:D I found my mistake :) Thanks for your support.

Comment: @SOuřaanGřg, That happens all the time. Welcome; glad that it helped.